# Український національний лінгвістичний корпус

Tags: discussion, resources, корпус

Ось посилання на цей корпус: http://unlc.icybcluster.org.ua/virt_unlc/

Хтось знає, як ним користуватися?

Чи можна десь зареєструватися, чи для цього треба бути їхнім співробітником?

Чи цей софт, який вони кажуть встановити, безпечний?

Comment: Ситуація на кшталт «коли програмісти полінувалися написати веб-інтерфейс». :-)

Comment: @bytebuster може, це просто закрите джерело?

Comment: Для нього є [інструкція](http://man.gov.ua/files/49/ORHANIZATsIYA.pdf), там написано: «Вхід до системи без реєстрації неможливий. Для реєстрації необхідні логін та пароль», а також «логін користувача (виділяється адміністратором при занесенні інформації про користувача до системи)» і «пароль <…> (видається адміністратором разом з логіном при занесенні інформації про користувача до системи)». Тобто по всьому виходить, що доступ обмежений.

Comment: А намагався писати їм на e-mail hostmaster@<назва домену> (не пам'ятаю, чому саме на цей — може, десь він згадувався) 5 місяців тому — не отримав жодної відповіді. E-mail'и, наведені внизу сторінки [тут](http://ulif.org.ua/) (їх там два: написано info@, але, якщо клацнути, відправляє на webmaster@), не працюють взагалі («Delivery Status Notification (Failure)»).

Comment: В коментарях на Facebook пишуть «він закритий, наскільки я знаю» (але припускаю, що люди, ніяк не пов'язані з цим корпусом).

Comment: Можливо, варто видалити його зі [списку](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9) — я просто сподівався все-таки якось прояснити цю ситуацію.

Comment: @Follower, див. [тут](//ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9) другий пункт. (Я поки що не видалив оцей дивний, але вточнив коментар і пересунув на останнє місце.)

Comment: Можеш впорядкувати за [прикладом](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/735/), індекси на початку й легко знаходити потрібну інформацію.

Comment: @Follower, поки що ні. Давно збираюся, але все руки не доходять. Але якщо хтось інший спробує — я не проти. (P.S.: Якщо пишете коментар не тій людині, яка є автором запитання/відповіді, то краще вказувати адресата через `@`, інакще сповіщення отримає не той.)

Answer (score 2):

- [Elektroniczny Polsko-Ukraiński Korpus Równoległy](http://www.domeczek.pl/~polukr/)
- [Google Books](http://books.google.com.ua/)
- [Lang-uk](http://lang.org.ua/uk/corpora/)

  - [Named-entity recognition anotation](//github.com/lang-uk/ner-uk) — на основі *[Браунського корпусу](//github.com/brown-uk/corpus)*
  - UberText — *тексти українських періодичних видань*
  - Корпус законів та правових актів
- [Лабораторія компʼютерної лінгвістики Інституту філології Київського національного університету імені Тараса Шевченка](http://mova.info/corpus.aspx)
- [Браунський корпус](//github.com/brown-uk/corpus) — *для машинної обробки, але можна [шукати через GitHub](//github.com/brown-uk/corpus/search?q=%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82)*
- [Институт русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова Московитской академии наук](http://www.ruscorpora.ru/search-para-uk.html) — *параллельный корпус*
- [Лейпцизький університет](http://corpora.informatik.uni-leipzig.de/en?corpusId=ukr_mixed_2014)
- [Український мовно-інформаційний фонд Національної академії наук України](http://unlc.icybcluster.org.ua/virt_unlc/) — *нема публічного доступу, лише для Windows*

Знаю, що не дуже по темі, але вирішив використати як початкову базу переліку.

Comment: о, гарно, можемо потім перенести на основний пост про джерела, як ви з Сашею обговорювали.

Comment: Вже почав у своїх текстових файлах. Але це займе чимало часу.

Comment: готуєте на базі того переліку, що є, нормально структуровані відповіді?